# T-SQL format contacts list of phone and adress

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I am trying to properly format my contact list in a way shown bellow. I am using T-SQL and so far I didn't manage to reproduce it the "normal" way, maybe I am missing some built in functionality of SSMS?

Desired formating looks like:

```
Person1   Phone 1
          Phone 2
                   Adress 1
                   Adress 2
Person 2  Phone 1
                  Adress 1
                  Adress 2
```

Btw, I have that data stored in three different tables, one with a person details, other two are phone details and adress details, related using foreign key to Person table ID.

Comment: I could show you enough T-SQL to do that, the thing is though you shouldn't do it. Export the data into a Word processor or use a reporting suite.

Comment: As a rule, formatting data for display should be done in an application, not the database. And it's curious that the telephone numbers cannot, apparently, be associated with an address (e.g. home, work, pub, ...).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but I forgot to mention that the question is for study purposes only, not to implement it on the real mvc or any other multi tier aplication. I am aware of that formating is supposed to be on some sort of reporting services or any kind of other UI, but I need it to solve my test. So if somebody would like to help me with this one, I would appreciate the answer.